# useCallback Hooks getting old state values and not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, usecallback

My Callback returning same state after calling it again and again

i am new to react hooks in react classes i could have used shouldcomponentupdate and could have solved this issue

but there isn't params in usecallback hook

```
import React, {
  useLayoutEffect,
  useState,
  useCallback,
  useEffect,
} from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform, YellowBox } from "react-native";
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from "react-navigation-header-buttons";
import HeaderButton from "../components/HeaderButton";
import { Switch } from "react-native-paper";
import Colors from "../constants/Colors";
//check use callback value first

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
  "Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state",
]);

const FilterSwitch = ({ label, state, onChange }) => (
  <View style={styles.filterContainer}>
    <Text>{label}</Text>
    <Switch
      value={state}
      trackColor={{ true: Colors.primaryColor }}
      thumbColor={Platform.OS === "android" ? Colors.primaryColor : ""}
      onValueChange={onChange}
    />
  </View>
);

const FiltersScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [isGlutenFree, setIsGlutenFree] = useState(false);
  const [isLactoseFree, setIsLactoseFree] = useState(false);
  const [isVegan, setIsVegan] = useState(false);
  const [isVegetarian, setIsVegetarian] = useState(false);

  const saveFilters = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(isGlutenFree);
    const appliedFilters = {
      glutenFree: isGlutenFree,
      lactoseFree: isLactoseFree,
      vegan: isVegan,
      isVegetarian: isVegetarian,
    };

    console.log(appliedFilters);
  }, [isGlutenFree, isLactoseFree, isVegan, isVegetarian]);


  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerTitle: "Filter Meals",
      headerLeft: () => (
        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
          <Item
            title="Menu"
            iconName="ios-menu"
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.toggleDrawer();
            }}
          />
        </HeaderButtons>
      ),
      headerRight: () => (
        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
          <Item
            title="Save"
            iconName="ios-save"
            onPress={() => saveFilters()}
          />
        </HeaderButtons>
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation]);
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Available Filters / Restrictions</Text>
      <FilterSwitch
        label="Gluten Free"
        state={isGlutenFree}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setIsGlutenFree(newValue);
        }}
      />
      <FilterSwitch
        label="Lactos Free"
        state={isLactoseFree}
        onChange={(newValue) => setIsLactoseFree(newValue)}
      />
      <FilterSwitch
        label="Vegan Free"
        state={isVegan}
        onChange={(newValue) => setIsVegan(newValue)}
      />
      <FilterSwitch
        label="Vegetarian Free"
        state={isVegetarian}
        onChange={(newValue) => setIsVegetarian(newValue)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  filterContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "80%",
    marginVertical: 15,
  },
  title: {
    fontFamily: "open-sans-bold",
    fontSize: 22,
    margin: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});
export default FiltersScreen;
```

How can i solve this problem?
I Have read official docs and i couldn't find any related issues there

Comment: `useCallback` just memoizes a callback (making sure it's reference stays the same unless one of it's dependencies has changed. Doesn't look like the one you wrote does anything (just creates an object and logs it). It will change if you call `setIsVegetarian` for example

Comment: i am calling every setState call on FilterSwitch custom component and i have provided every value even my state is changing on every render

Comment: your `useNavigationEffect` hook doesn't have your `saveFilters` callback as a dependency so it will never call the "new" callback (with your changed state). Add it to your dependency list

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue with your code is that, even though you have provided `useCallback` with all dependecy array, you are only using the `first closure value` of the function within `onPress={() => saveFilters()}` since this code is executed inside `useLayoutEffect` and that is run only on `navigation` change

The solution here is to `update navigation options` on both `navigation` change and on `saveFilters` change

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerTitle: "Filter Meals",
      headerLeft: () => (
        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
          <Item
            title="Menu"
            iconName="ios-menu"
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.toggleDrawer();
            }}
          />
        </HeaderButtons>
      ),
      headerRight: () => (
        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
          <Item
            title="Save"
            iconName="ios-save"
            onPress={() => saveFilters()}
          />
        </HeaderButtons>
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation, saveFilters]);
```

> **P.S.** This is the kind of situation where I feel hooks implementation sometimes becomes hacky or inefficient. Also debugging
> `closures` is way more difficult then debugging `context`(this in
> class component)

Comment: saved me , when I started to doubt my react skills :)